# Adding color label key to corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am trying to add a 2nd color label key to my corrplot heatmap. I have generated the heatmap using the r values. I have two datasets, one with the data that I used to make the correlation matrix. The 2nd is the list of the genes and their sources. I would like to add a color label on the left of the plot indicating the source of each gene. Below are the categories I want to add:

Gene   Source

X       Human

Y       HumanMouse

Z       Mouse

[image: my current corrplot heatmap]

Thank you

EDIT: Here's is the code for my heatmap

```
corrplot(upreg_cor$r, type = "upper", tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 90, tl.cex = 0.5)
```

The data I used to create the correlation matrix then heatmap looks like this

```
Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 
0.5    0.2   0.3   0.1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post simplified versions of your data and your existing code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey my data is very simply, just several columns with numeric data that I used to create the correlation matrix. Then I used that to create the heatmap.

Comment: corrplot(upreg_cor$r, type = "upper", tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 90, tl.cex = 0.5)

This is my code, I just want to figure out a way to match the source of the gene with a color label on the left of the plot I attached

Comment: This code should be added to the question. Note the first answer below also pointed out your lack of sample data/code. People will always complain about this, so best to just post it right away.

Answer (score 4):

You do not provide any data nor your current code, so we cannot work with that. 
I will use some simple built in data to illustrate. What you will have to do is to figure out which labels get which colors to build the right color map.

The main thing that you need to know is that the parameter `tl.col` controls the color of the label text and it takes a vector so that each label can be a different color.  In my example,  I chose to make the Sepal measurements be red and the Petal measurements be blue.

```
library(corrplot)

LabelCol = c("red", "red", "blue", "blue")
corrplot(cor(iris[,1:4]), type="upper",  tl.col=LabelCol)
```

[image: Corrplot with Multiple Label colors]

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I just added some comments with my code, its very simple. I am trying to add another color bar like the one on the right of yours but instead it labels if each gene in my plot is from Human, HumanMouse or Mouse

Comment: do you know how I could add a 2nd color bar on the left to indicated which group each gene belongs to? Appreciate your help

Comment: This colors different labels when `diag = FALSE`, any alternative?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie  This looks like a bug in `corrplot`. My only suggestion is to report it as a bug at the [githib repository](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues)